# Проблема с путями к файлам. React приложение на Django

Tags: django, reactjs

Есть следующая проблема:

Пишу приложение на React и в некоторых компонентах я использую изображения и пути к ним выглядят следующим образом: `<img alt="img" src="./assets/img/photo1.jpg" />`.

Когда я собираю bundle и кидаю на django сервер, я получаю ошибки, что файлы не найдены. Все assets я скопировал в папку static, то есть единственное различие в путях к файлам - папка static/путь_к_файлу

Есть конечно вариант локально положить assets в папку static и в приложении прописать пути с указанием папки static, но есть ли какой-то способ лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В setting.py

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

И меняешь `<img alt="img" src="./assets/img/photo1.jpg" />` на `<img alt="img" src="{%static "./assets/img/photo1.jpg"%}" />` 
ну и еще добавить в начале html страницы {%load static%}
если я конечно правильно понял вопрос

Comment: немного не так, я хочу не переписывать реакт, но чтобы каким-то образом джанго подхватывал, что перед относительным путем нужно воткнуть путь до статик директории

Comment: @Zimovik007 так по сути не обязательно создавать вообще папку static.
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
с реактом не знаком, поэтому может не совсем понимаю в чем дело

Comment: в общем-то, вы правы, стоит так сделать

Comment: @Zimovik007 ну еще можно так указать путь к папке static, если он в другом каталоге
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale/static"),)
У меня так работает, правда не уверен на сколько корректна такая запись)
отметьте ответ как полезен, если он вам помог:)